# Suitescript 2.0 Netsuite query for Show Period End Transactions

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am using N/query module for get transactions, my question is how to implement in this query the setting of N/search module "Show Period End Transactions".

I only find settings with N search module didnt find any similar with query.